# How to open the url when click the edge in Echarts tree

Tags: echarts

When I use Echarts tree, clicking nodes will trigger events, but clicking edge will not trigger events.
How to open the url when click the edge in Echarts tree ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZeuc.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [ECharts.events](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#events.Mouse%20events)?

Try this:

```js
    this.echartInstance.on(
      'click', { seriesName: 'yourSeriesName', dataType: 'edge' }, (params: any) => {
        console.log(params)
      }
    )
```

Hope this helps